# TypeScript error "TS2354: This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found"

Tags: typescript

I have reduced a problem with TypeScript to the following example. When trying to run tsc, I get the following error message but `tslib` should be available.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mclean-n9vvi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```sh
$ tsc --noEmit --project ./tsconfig.json

index.js:3:8 - error TS2354: This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.

3 const {ArgumentParser} = require('argparse');
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Found 1 error.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "tsc --noEmit --project ./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/argparse": "1.0.38",
    "argparse": "1.0.10",
    "tslib": "1.11.1",
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "*.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

const {ArgumentParser} = require('argparse');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has now been confirmed as a bug in TypeScript https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37991

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install "tslib" using the following command.

```
npm i -g tslib
```

Answer (score -1):

I Resolve this issue by using below `copy-anything` npm command

```
npm i copy-anything
```